# maven-scr-plugin shows No annotation processors found in classpath error

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I am trying to build OSGi bundle using the maven build tool.

Using the maven-scr-plugin and maven-bundle-plugin to build the project,

```
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.26.4</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.26.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Export-Package>com.osgi.mini.project.*</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But when the maven-scr-plugin is added to the pom file it was throwing an exception when building the maven project. In eclipse, the "execution" tag is highlighted under the maven-scr-plugin which was causing throwing the below exception,

```
No annotation processors found in classpath. (org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.26.4:scr:generate-scr-scrdescriptor:process-classes)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No annotation processors found in classpath.
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.mojo.SCRDescriptorMojo.execute(SCRDescriptorMojo.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$8(MavenImpl.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$1(MavenBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.lambda$0(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.apache.felix.scrplugin.SCRDescriptorFailureException: No annotation processors found in classpath.
    at org.apache.felix.scrplugin.helper.AnnotationProcessorManager.<init>(AnnotationProcessorManager.java:78)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add corresponding annotation dependency to your `pom.xml`.

The [documentation of Maven SCR Plugin](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin-use.html) stated that:

> If you want to use the annotations from the Apache Felix project, add this dependency to your pom:
>
> ```xml
> <project>
>   ...
>   <dependencies>
>     ...
>     <dependency>
>          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
>          <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
>          <version>1.12.0</version>
>          <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     ...
>   </dependencies>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```

And that:

> If you want to process the standard annotations with the maven-scr-plugin add this dependency:
>
> ```xml
> <project>
>   ...
>   <dependencies>
>     ...
>     <dependency>
>          <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
>          <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.ds-annotations</artifactId>
>          <version>1.2.10</version>
>          <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     ...
>   </dependencies>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```